# Do all the seach engines rank the same way?

Tags: seo, pagerank

I know the algorithms that is used by search engines can't be exactly the same. But do I need to take bing and other search engines into consideration when building a site, or will my site be optimized for them if I just focus on optimizing my site for Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most often optimization for Google means clear page structure, sitemaps, fast page speed, good incoming links, etc. This of course optimizes for other search engines. Nonetheless you should at least look at the other major search engines, most importantly Bing. A good placement at Google is often also a good placement in all other search engines.

Comment: agreed to @neo It's good to focus for google first, then there will be hardly any optimization trick left for other search engines as they follow google's rules too (almost)

Comment: @DamodarBashyal is that because Google is the leading provider out there?

Comment: @MohamedAnisDahmani I think so because i get +80% visitors from google only.

Comment: So that may be because most of the people online tend to use Google for performing searches.